# Google Apps Script CardService.newTextInput does not show for one user

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following code. It basically just shows a text field and a button, for a search functionality:

```
function main(e){
    var cardMain = CardService.newCardBuilder().setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader());
    
    cardMain.addSection(createMainSection(e));

    return cardMain.build();
}

function createMainSection(e){
  // Define actions
  var actionSearch = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("searchfunction");
  
  var section = CardService.newCardSection()
    .setHeader("<b><font color='#1a1a1a'>Post to Bitrix</font></b>")
    .addWidget(CardService.newTextInput()
      .setFieldName("Search")
      .setTitle("Enter search here")
      .setHint("Search company, contact, lead, deal, workgroup")
      .setValue(sender)
    )
    .addWidget(CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText("Search")
        .setOnClickAction(actionSearch)
        .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
    );

 
  return section;
}
```

It shows like this:
[image: Search]

But for one user, on three different computers, using different browsers, the text field does not show up:
[image: Search with error]

If I set the text input to be multiline

```
.addWidget(CardService.newTextInput()
      .setFieldName("Search")
      .setTitle("Enter search here")
      .setHint("Search company, contact, lead, deal, workgroup")
      .setValue(sender)
      .setMultiline(true)
    )
```

It does show up:
[image: Multiline search]

Is there any reason for this UI rendering issues for this particular user? It's not the computer nor the browser (I think) as we have tried on three different computers (including a Mac). Could there be a user setting somewhere the affects UI rendering?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's more interesting about this case is the fact that only one user is affected, taking aside the fact that different browsers and Operative systems have already been tried, have you been able to check if the text box is even attempted to be created by the browser? every browser has their own version but on chrome you can use the [DevTools] (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/#chrome-menu) to see the HTML of the website you are visiting, does the box show there?

Comment: I just got informed that it also happens to two other users.  The HTML code for the input not is not rendered on the account where it's missing. There is HTML code for the header and the button. So it looks like there is an error in the rendering service in the backend of Apps Script CardService.

Comment: Maybe Google is rolling out an update, and it depends if the user has it or not. [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EAggpQJ9THITuuQUDdocaGgrIdOMjjsR/view?usp=sharing) is a screenshot of two Chrome browser windows on the same computer, but each has a different profile. The text input has multline=true, and they appear different for each user. Same Chrome browser, same computer.

Comment: Based on your latest comment I believe it might be worth it to get ahead of the curve and try reporting this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113&pli=1) before it affects more users.

Comment: Thank you. I created a thread in Google Groups, others have experienced the same, and an IssueTrackTracker post has been [created](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/279506028).